# Estimate loads for the peak traffic by calculus

Tags: c#, calculus

I found a interesting topic realted to [Q&A With Nine Great Programmers](http://www.dodgycoder.net/2012/09/q-with-nine-great-programmers.html) ,

In the Q3 section : Do you think mathematics and/or physics are an important skill for a programmer? Why?

One of the programer Steve Yegge says :

I had to estimate loads for the peak traffic hour of the day for a service whose load "follows the sun" in an approximate sine curve. The simplest way to make the estimate was to integrate over 1/24th of the curve at a specific time. If I hadn’t known calculus, I would not have known how to make a reasonably accurate estimate

I'm curious about how can i estimate load by  calculus  , is there any example someone

could help me understand this interesting problem .

Comment: Do you understand what he/she is saying there and why?

Comment: I have no idea why he use calculus in estimating loads , 
Because we could record every incoming request and get the status of 
load traffic , isn't it ?